# Use int as month when constructing date

Tags: go

When I supply an `int` as an argument to `time.Date` for `month`, it works ([Example](https://play.golang.org/p/nNArrTEq0N)):

```
time.Date(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

Why, when I try to convert a `string` to `int` and then use that variable, I get the error:

```
cannot use mStr (type int) as type time.Month in argument to time.Date
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/-XFNZHK476

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to convert the value to the proper type:

```
import(
    "fmt" 
    "time" 
    "strconv"
) 

func main() {
    var m, _ = strconv.Atoi("01")
     // Now convert m to type time.Month 
    fmt.Println(time.Date(2016, time.Month(m), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC))
}
```

You converted it to a type `int`, but the 2nd parameter of `time.Date()` is of type `time.Month` so it would give you an error that you are not using the correct type.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'casting' in Go. It's a type conversion, casting in the C sense is less strict.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're declaring the type as a `time.Month`, it is not an int, it is a `time.Month`. In the second example the type is an int. If you were to do a cast, like in this example it would work as you expect; https://play.golang.org/p/drD_7KiJu4

If in your first example you declared `m` as an `int` or just used the `:=` operator (the implied type would be int) and you would get the same error as in the second example. Demonstrated here; https://play.golang.org/p/iWc-2Mpsly

Answer (score 1):

The Go compiler only casts constants to types on its own. Variables need to be explicitly cast.